# Serialization bytes are added to the servlet response outputstream, how to avoid it?

Tags: java, servlets, serialization, deserialization, outputstream

In doPost, return the bitmap

```
        String mimeType = sc.getMimeType(filename);
        // Set content type
        resp.setContentType(mimeType);
        // Set content size
        File file = new File(filename);
        resp.setContentLength((int)file.length());

        // Open the file and output streams
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        // Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            outStream.write(buf, 0, count);
        }
```

Test with fiddler, 4 extra bytes are added to the header and 4 bytes are dropped from the bmp. They are AC ED 00 05, which is from serialization algorithm. It causes the bmp unrecognizable.

How to avoid these serialization bytes, when creating the output stream?

Comment: These are not 'serialization bytes', and they are not added to the servlet response stream. Whatever was in the file is copied exactly. NB Don't set `content-length`: the container does that for you. You coudl usefully increase the buffer size to say 8192 bytes.

Comment: You didn't show the definition of `outStream`.

Comment: ejp  yes, they are about serialization bytes. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html